# Replacing word in a sentence by another one work but does not output well the punctuation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I use a list of synonym to replace word in my sentence by them. The function works but there is a slightly problem with the output

```
#Function 

eda(t, alpha_sr=0.1, num_aug=3)


Original : "Un abricot est bon."

New sentence : 'Un aubercot est bon .'
```

As you can see the replacement was made but the punctuation is far the last word est the original. I would like to modify so that I will obtain this result for each pounction.

```
New sentence : 'Un aubercot est bon.'

augmented_sentences.append(' '.join(a_words)) # the problem arise here since, I joined the words after splitting them the punctuation is also join with space.
```

Sinc I am working with some quite long review, the punctuation is really important.
The code is below :

```
def cleaning(texte):
    
    texte = re.sub(r"<iwer>.*?</iwer>", " ", str(texte))  # clean
    return texte

def eda(sentence, alpha_sr=float, num_aug=int):

    sentence = cleaning(sentence)
    sent_doc = nlp(sentence)
    words = [token.text for token in sent_doc if token.pos_ != "SPACE"]
    num_words = len(words)


    augmented_sentences = []
    num_new_per_technique = int(num_aug/4)+1

    if (alpha_sr > 0):
        n_sr = max(1, int(alpha_sr*num_words))
        for _ in range(num_new_per_technique):
            a_words = synonym_replacement(words, n_sr)
            print(a_words)
            augmented_sentences.append(' '.join(a_words)) # the problem is here since, I joined the words adfter using

    shuffle(augmented_sentences)

    #trim so that we have the desired number of augmented sentences
    if num_aug >= 1:
        augmented_sentences = augmented_sentences[:num_aug]
    else:
        keep_prob = num_aug / len(augmented_sentences)
        augmented_sentences = [s for s in augmented_sentences if random.uniform(0, 1) < keep_prob]

    #append the original sentence
    augmented_sentences.append(sentence)
    
    #print(len(augmented_sentences))
    return augmented_sentences

def synonym_replacement(words, n):
    
    new_words = words.copy()

    random_word_list = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]
    random_word_list = ' '.join(new_words)
    #print("random list :", random_word_list)
    
    sent_doc = nlp(random_word_list)
    random_word_list = [token.lemma_ for token in sent_doc if token.pos_ == "NOUN" or token.pos_ == "ADJ" or token.pos_ == "VERB" or token.pos_ == "ADV"]
    
    random.shuffle(random_word_list)
    num_replaced = 0
    for random_word in random_word_list:

        synonyms = get_synonyms(random_word)
        if len(synonyms) >= 1:
            synonym = random.choice(list(synonyms))
            new_words = [synonym if word == random_word else word for word in new_words]
            #print("replaced", random_word, "with", synonym)
            num_replaced += 1
        if num_replaced >= n: #only replace up to n words
            break

    #this is stupid but we need it, trust me
    sentence = ' '.join(new_words)
    new_words = sentence.split(' ')

    return new_words

def get_synonyms(word):
    synonyms = []
    for k_syn, v_syn in word_syn_map.items(): 
        if k_syn == word:
            print(v_syn)
            synonyms.extend(v_syn)
    synonyms = set(synonyms)
    if word in synonyms:
        synonyms.remove(word)
    return list(synonyms)
```

the dictionnary of synonym look like this :

```
#word_syn_map

defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'ADN': ['acide désoxyribonucléique', 'acide désoxyribonucléique'],
'abdomen': ['bas-ventre',
                         'bide',
                         'opisthosome',
                         'panse',
                         'ventre',
                         'bas-ventre',
                         'bide',
                         'opisthosome',
                         'panse',
                         'ventre'],
             'abricot': ['aubercot', 'michemis', 'aubercot', 'michemis']})
```

## tokenization

```
import stanza
import spacy_stanza

stanza.download('fr')
nlp = spacy_stanza.load_pipeline('fr', processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma')
```

Comment: You are iterating sentence by sentence and doing the synonym replacement, after the word replacement and joining[ i.e after augmented_sentences.append(' '.join(a_words))], find " ." string and replace it with "."

Comment: I do not understand your point ? could you be clearer ?

Answer (score 0):

Two answers to this:

1. I can't see your `nlp` function, so I don't know how you're tokenising the string, but it looks like you're doing it by treating punctuation as a separate token. That's why it's picking up a space, because it's being treated like any other word. You either need to adjust your tokenisation algorithm so that it includes the punctuation in the word or if you can't do that then you need to do an extra pass through the words list at the start to stick punctuation back onto the token it belongs to (ie. if a given token is punctuation, and you'll need a list of punctuation tokens, then glue it together with the token before). Either way then you need to adjust your matching algorithm so it ignores punctuation and matches the rest of the word.
2. This feels like you're overcomplicating the problem. I'd be inclined to do something like this:

```py
import re

def get_synonym(wordmatch):
  synonym = # pick one synonym for word at random
  return wordmatch.group(1) + synonym + matchobj.group(2)

new_sentence = sentence.copy # Or however you want to take a copy of sentence, eg. copy.copy()
for original_word in defaultdict:
  wordexp = re.compile((^|" ") + word + ([ .!?-,])) # Add more punctuation to this list
  new_sentence = re.sub(wordexp, get_synonym, new_sentence, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Not guaranteed to work, I haven't tested it (and you'll certainly need to do something to maintain capitalisation or it'll lowercase everything), but I'd do something with regexes, myself.

Comment: for nlp , i used stanza_spacy and  download the model in the nlp pbject. I modify. so that you can see: import stanza
import spacy_stanza

stanza.download('fr')
nlp = spacy_stanza.load_pipeline('fr', processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma')